# iscroll link ajax

Tags: ajax, iscroll4

I've been at this for a few hours so I hope someone can help me with this and not just tell me to GOOGLE it.

I'm using iscroll because of its great features of fixed header/footer.

I have links in the footer.  When in normal safari, it all works fine.  When the webapp is saved to the home screen, and then launched, after a link is clicked they close the webapp and launch safari.

I've tried AJAX with no good luck.

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative links rather than absolute links.

for example use links such as

`/link/to/page` or `link/to/page`

rather than

`http://domainname.com/link/to/page`

or

`http://www.domainname.com/link/to/page`